# How do I use tf2ss() with discrete-time systems?

Tags: function, matlab, transfer, state-space

A have a discrete time transfer function,

> H(z<sup>-1</sup>) = B(z<sup>-1</sup>) / A(z<sup>-1</sup>) = (b<sub>0</sub> + b<sub>1</sub>z<sup>-1</sup>) / (a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>z<sup>-1</sup> + a<sub>2</sub>z<sup>-2</sup>).

whose numerator and denominator are represented in the code as:

> Num = [b<sub>0</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>];
>   Den = [a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>];
>   T<sub>s</sub> = 0.01; % Sampling period`

How do I use `tf2ss()` to obtain the `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` state space matrices?
Do I directly call `tf2ss()` like we do in continuous time system?
Or is there any other built-in Matlab function for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something in your question, but you can use it simply like this:

```
[A, B, C, D] = tf2ss(Den, Num);
```

You can also refer to the [official `tf2ss` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/ref/tf2ss.html) to confirm this.

Comment: So, we do no additional operation when working with discrete systems?

Comment: In this simple case there is no need (however sometimes it _is_ necessary to consider the implications of sampling).

Answer (score 2):

Transfer functions to state space conversions are equal in continuous and discrete models. But, if you want the matrices in a system represented discretely you might want to do something like this

S = ss(tf(Num,Den,T))

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should build your continuous state space model by using this:
**sys_state_space = tf2ss(a,b)**
after that you should use this:
**sys_ss_discrete = c2d(sys_state_space,T*-sampling*,'zoh')**

then you have the state space discrete model of the system.